# Using a custom HTML form to create joomla articles

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have a custom HTML form that i would like to use to create Joomla! 3.5 Articles with it. but every other extensions offers me "extra fields" and no way of customizing it or any of it's functionalities.

please do not suggest me extensions, I would like something more reliable even if it involves creating a new module/extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible,You Can build a own Plugin to add custom fields:

[Adding a Custom Field - Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin)

[how to add custom fields articles in joomla - Third party docs](https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/203-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-articles-in-joomla)